# PHP Facebook v5 get session from cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, facebook-php-sdk

I have setup Facebook login for my website and everything works except for when the PHP session expires. After it expires and I refresh the page my website thinks that the user is logged out. After refreshing a page a second time it logs the user back in. I'm assuming is something that the JavaScript library is doing. I don't want to have to rely on the JavaScript library because I'm making Ajax calls and it needs to be able to relogin if the session is expired through PHP only.

I've been printing out $_COOKIE to keep track of the Facebook cookies and I see that after the session they still exist:

```
Array
(
    [fbm_1575590742733556] => base_domain=.mysite.us
    [fbsr_1575590742733556] => 1OdQYsdikidaL08RnVXbEc1ZmU3OTNBcHVDONlZEVjckVPZGZSeWZwT1Z6ZTEyVWVXaXY5b1VlSUJqMFo5UnhKRnFlMUJxV0hQMmticGVDRnBPRmt5dsafdsafsdfdsafdsafasdfdsdsafdsaZXzg1T3dmS1JIdzZ1bjRUU3pKMnEyTXF6Vm5aUazS2AtDxUav3xMNz2PAPl2dyfE.eyJhbGdvcml0aG0iOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiIsImNvZGUiOiJBUUF1ZVZ2UU01TkZtVUwtQXYyQXla1c1VURkYmtBbHJOdS04OWxYUWZRc0laUTd3T2xhX0RqRU5EMWh2MklBa21rTnpNZHpueTEFROVR4Yk5PYWVTbDFMZG5vMTJnaU1IS0ZPNEdHMXFYUmx6RzFWQ2tzQ0N1ZVZDU2lmYllfUEtaOGxpUktNNFM0RlBHa3pS1wLUxZQlhDVHhUMXFMWjVqNHBVdVZORVFvMGNaMmtSeUI0T202TzAwNDd2ZFhTYmRPOTU3N0VWZEczbUVyaUpkZVhPdHNzOGwtZl9Hc1JKayIsImlzc3VlZF9hdCI6MTQ2NjczNDMxMSwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjEwMTgzOTQ5MDI0NTQyNSJ9
)
```

On every page load I call the function:

```
public static function CheckToken() 
    {
        // Get a token if we dont have one
        if (!isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token'])) 
        {
            $helper = self::$api->getJavaScriptHelper();

            try {
                // Get the acess token
                $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

                // OAuth 2.0 client handler
                $oAuth2Client = FacebookProxy::$api->getOAuth2Client();

                // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
                $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Store the access token
                $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
            }
            catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) 
            {
                // When Graph returns an error
                $response['errors'][] = 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            } 
            catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
            {
                // When validation fails or other local issues
                $response['errors'][] = 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        // Set the default access token
        if(isset($_SESSION['fb_access_token']))
        {
            self::$api->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['fb_access_token']);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static function SignInUser() 
    {
        $errors = array();

        if(isset($_GET['test'])) echo "CHECK TOKEN";

        if(self::CheckToken() == true)
        {
            if(isset($_GET['test'])) ECHO "WE HAVE A TOKEN";
            // Get info about the user
            $fbuser = self::GetMyInfo(array("id","email","name","first_name","last_name"));

            // Check if there is already a user with this info
            $user = User::GetBy("id_facebook", $fbuser['id']);

            if($user->isValid() == false) 
            {
                $errors = null;

                $user = User::Create($fbuser['email'], null, $errors);

                // User already exists
                if($user == false) {
                    $user = User::GetByEmail($fbuser['email']);
                }
            }

            if($user != null) 
            {
                $user->Set("id_facebook", $fbuser['id']);
                $user->Set("first_name", $fbuser['first_name']);
                $user->Set("last_name", $fbuser['last_name']);
                $user->Save($errors);
            }
            else
            {
                $errors[] = "There was an error creating your account.";
            }

            if(count($errors) == 0)
            {
                if(isset($_GET['test'])) ECHO "SIGNING IN!";
                $user->SignIn();
            }
        }

        if(isset($_GET['test'])) ECHO "END TOKEN";

        return $errors;
    }
```

I think my issue is somewhere in the CheckToken function. Is there a way to get the token from the Facebook library? Is it just ask simple as resetting $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] to the string stored in the cookie? I'm assuming that the number after fbsr_ is dynamically created so how do I determine what to load. If there are multiple users authenticated are their multiple cookies that could potentially be stored here?

**Update:**
I manually tried setting the session token to the string stored in the cookie but that is now giving me facebook exception errors:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookServerException' with message 'Expected 1 '.' in the input between the postcard and the payload' in facebook_v5/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php:105 Stack trace: #0 facebook_v5/FacebookResponse.php(210): Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException::create(Object(Facebook\FacebookResponse)) #1 facebook_v5/FacebookResponse.php(255): Facebook\FacebookResponse->makeException() #2 facebook_v5/FacebookResponse.php(82): Facebook\FacebookResponse->decodeBody() #3 facebook_v5/FacebookClient.php(225): Facebook\FacebookResponse->__construct(Object(Facebook\FacebookRequest), '{"error":{"mess...', 400, Array) #4 facebook_v5/Facebook.php(504): Facebook\FacebookClient->sendRequest(Object(Fa in facebook_v5/Exceptions/FacebookResponseException.php on line 105
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as its not possible to restart the session with PHP strictly from the Facebook SDK. This requires the JavaScript library to relogin the user as the Facebook cookies are under the Facebook domain.

The way I approached this was to integrate Facebook login with my own login system. When a user authenticates with Facebook, I then create them an account and store the Facebook access token in a database. I then create my own cookie to auto log them into their account. If they come back and their session doesn't have an access token it can then look up the token in the database. This way is also better because then you can always run cron jobs as the user if need be (such as updating friends or whatever).